# Why isn't this code reversing user inputted text?

Tags: java, string, for-loop, substring

```
System.out.println("type something to get it back reversed...");
Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);

String x = sc1.nextLine();//user input

for(int i = x.length(); i > 0; i--) 
{   
System.out.print(x.substring(i));
}
```

In this code, I want to take user-inputted text and output it in reverse order (i.e. dog = god) with a for-loop and the substring method. The above code is non-functional.

For example...
-when I input "dog", I get "gog".
-when I input "computer", I get "rerteruterputermputeromputer"

It never outputs the first letter of the text. I'd be very grateful if somebody could help me out and explain this to me :)

Comment: You know `substring(i)` will give everything from `i` to the end of the string? Maybe you want `charAt(i)`. Also, your `for` loop as the wrong endpoints.

Comment: I know how to use the charAt function, but for this particular assignment I have to use substring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the API for the String class. The String.substring(int index) method creates a substring from the parameter index to the end of the String (so if x is dog, the x.substring(0) results in 'dog'. Perhaps you wish to use the two parameter substring method. Also note the indexes of the loop, starting at length - 1 and ending at 0

```
for ( int i = x.length()-1; i >= 0; i-- ){
    System.out.print(x.substring(i, i+1));
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between ending at the end of the string when I use the String,substring(int index) method and ending at "i+1" in the two parameter substring method?

Comment: As explained in the answer, the single parameter substring method returns a String that starts at index and ends at the end of the String. The two parameter substring methods let's you specify the end index of the returned String

Answer (score 2):

`substring(i)` returns everything in your string from `i` to the end. To get the character at position `i` in a string, use `charAt(i)`. 
Also, the last index of the string is `x.length()-1`. The first is zero. So your loop should be something like:

```
for (int i = x.length()-1; i>=0; --i) {
     System.out.print(x.charAt(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As copeg explained, `substring()` returns all characters after the character i. An easier solution would be to use `charAt()`:

```
for(int i = x.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) {   
    System.out.print(x.charAt(i));
}
```